# Fire async calls in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I've got some code right now that looks like this:

```
const a = await function1();
const b = await function2();
const c = await function3();
```

However I'm trying to optimise for speed and don't want the delays. I have tried doing the following

```
[const a, const b, const c] = await Promise.all([function1, function2, function3)]
```

This works fine however the problem I then have is that I can't preserve the order of the calls initiated from my machine. As I send out a nonce on each request the end server will decline the request if it goes in order 1 -> 3 -> 2 instead of 1->2->3.

Is there a way to use the Promise.all which doesn't wait for each function to complete but still retain the order of the calls?

Comment: preserve the order of what? The response you get will be ordered?

Comment: Order it is sent from the server. Will update

Comment: What do you mean by "_end server will decline the request if it goes in order 1 -> 3 -> 2 instead of 1->2->3._"

Comment: Why is order important here? Does function2 depends on function1 in any way?

Comment: So, you *cannot* alter the order, you need to go in sequence but...you're trying to optimise and to do so you remove the sequence? I don't get it. If it's impossible to make the requests in a different order, then you cannot really optimise anything here, you *need* to wait for each to be handled. If you *are* able to run the requests in parallel, then the order doesn't matter.

Comment: The endpoint I am calling will decline if the order it receives the calls is not in that given order

Comment: Was just curious if its possible to start each call in a particular order but not wait for the results of it to continue?

Comment: Then the solution is not to do concurrent requests. They will get affected by network latency, even if you send them off in the right order (as your code *does*). You can a) change your API to allow doing all parts together with only one request b) change your API to ignore out-of-order requests if received in a short timeframe c) get three independent nonces for your client d) just do the requests sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([function1(), function2(), function3()];
```

the synchronous part of `function1` will run first, followed by the synchronous part of `function2`, followed by the synchronous part of `function3`. At that point, they're in a race for completion. Regardless of the order they complete in, you'll get the results in order (`a` is the result of `function1`, `b` of `function2`, etc.).

If the server requires that the **asynchronous** part of `function1` finish before `function2` starts, then you have to use your original code. The only control you have in the client-side code is when the processes *start*.

**However**, that doesn't mean it's not possible to optimize them a bit, but it depends a lot on what they do. For instance, if the important thing is that you receive the *headers* sent in response to `function1`'s request before you start `function2`, but `function1` does further processing after receiving the headers (such as reading and doing something with the body of the response), you can optimize that but splitting `function1` into two parts: The part that starts the process and consumes the headers, and the part that consumes the body and does something with it.

If you did that, you'd do it like this:

```
// Do the first part in series
const r1 = await function1PartA();
const r2 = await function2PartA();
const r3 = await function3PartA();
// Do the remainder in parallel
const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([
    function1PartB(r1),
    function2PartB(r2),
    function3PartB(r3)
]);
```